# Can I use return from a coroutine when calling another coroutine?

Tags: c++

Suppose that I have the followings:

```cpp
Task<int> A() { co_return 1; }
Task<int> B() { co_return co_await A(); }
Task<int> C() { return A(); }
```

Both B and C compile just fine. So I'm leaning towards using `return` since it looks simpler but it feels awkward to not use `co_return` from a coroutine. What's the best practice?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the case for C++, but in C# returning the Task instead of awaiting it would mean the function is not async, thus the state machine is not generated for that function. This is not really a problem, excerpt for traceability: when an exception is thrown in A you would only see that where that's awaited. Thus you could see that it's called via B, but not that it's called via C. (The outer awaiting call will always catch the excepting though, the trace will just not be complete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `C` is not really much of a coroutine, is it? It just returns one. Well, all coroutines in C++ are like that from outside, I like that design choice. In Python, you would have to mark `B` as `async` and could *not* mark `C` as async (or you would have to await it twice).

Next, `B` is not exactly the same because you "unwrap" the integer from the task and return a new task from it, there might be some efficiency overhead of that unless the compiler can optimize through `co_return co_await` which I have no idea about.  `B` is also rewritten while `C` is not, but unless the code is heavily templatized, the impact on compilation time should be minimal.

I would opt for `C`, it is the most natural, `A` returns a `Task` and you just forward it outside. It's less confusing for the reader and most optimal for the compiler, I fail to see any downsides.